# Wanting an explanation to the solution method of the system of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please can anybody help me with explaining, in detail, why and how the author solves the system of differential equations by such a step (see below)? How the equation 6.3 is formed step by step? Why such a column basis is valid? It would be extremely helpful if someone knows the name of the method or could give an exemplification. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms multiplied by $\mu$ & $\nu$ are modeling diffusion (this is a standard center difference scheme). What we know about the continuous diffusion operator (with appropriate boundary conditions) is that its eigenvectors are sines &/or cosines. If you prefer, they're exponentials with imaginary powers (the two are equivalent by Euler's formula). This is just the discrete analog: note that the vectors employed for the change of coordinates are *exactly* such complex exponentials evaluated at the grid points. You can check yourself that they are eigenvectors of the discretized diffusion matrix.

Comment: Thanks very much. You said "they are eigenvectors of the discretized diffusion matrix", can you also point out what is the diffusion matrix so that I could evaluate its eigenvectors. And at same time, the eigenvectors seem to be independent of a, b, c, d, u and v, whether the matrix is the coefficients in the parentheses？

Comment: Sure, the discretized diffusion matrix is a tridiagonal matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $-2$ and all superdiagonal and subdiagonal entries equal to $1$. (See also your ODE system (6.2) above.) Caveat: boundary conditions affect the top and bottom rows (this is reflected in how $x_{-1}$ and $y_{-1}$ are defined).  Note, additionally, that (6.3) will only diagonalize the part of your linear ODE system pertaining to diffusion; it will not do so for the part relating to $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I checked with a diffusion matrix A of a ring of five cells: -2 on its diagonal entries, 1 on the sub-and super-diagonal entries, and a_15=a_51=1 being the boundary condition (a ring). The eigenvector given by Matlab is not the same as the exp. part defined in 6.3. The eigenvectors calculated are all real numbers for the matrix A, and dose not have a vector with all 1s as its entries. But 6.3 suggests such a vector when s=0, for all r, the entries is 1. Please can you let me know where I got lost and went wrong. I appreciate!

Comment: You use periodic BCs, so I expect the eigenfunctions of the diffusion operator to be translation invariant. No wonder you didn't get the exponentials. I don't have access to MATLAB right now so I can't do it myself, but I'd suggest that you calculate the action of the diffusion matrix on said exponential and see whether you get a multiple of it. As for the constant vector (=spatially uniform pattern in the continuous case), of course that's an eigenvector (corresponding eigenvalue: zero)  for your matrix $[-2,1,0,0,1 ; 1,-2,1,0,0 ; 0,1-2,1,0 ; 0,0,1,-2,1 ; 1,0,0-2,1]$! Check your numerics!

Comment: (Btw, keep me posted on this, I enjoy remembering that stuff. & do upvote/formally accept my answer if it ends up working.)

Comment: Good idea, let me check first.

Comment: You are right, it is indeed. But then why didn't I get the exponentials at the first place? And where dose the eigenvectors equation (6.3) come from? Does it relate to fourier theory? I must have a big gap here. Please can you remind me, as detail as possible, thanks!

Comment: As I said, periodic BCs mean that not only cosines **but** also shifted cosines (e.g., sines) are eigenvectors to the same eigenvalue. The same goes, then, for linear combinations of those.  MATLAB picks up one particular case; (6.3) picks up another. This eq. is, indeed, an eigendecomposition - the discrete analog of Fourier. More detail than that I won't provide, & this discussion is closed from my side. If you need to understand this in detail (it is HW? research? work? s'thing else?), try writing down the diffusion matrix, guessing eigenvectors and working out what the eigendecomp. does.

Comment: It's a lot of help, thanks again!